# Real places in Fictional writing

Tags: fiction

I am writing a fictional novel. Is it okay to add factual information amongst my characters? For example my destination in the story, or geographical areas in my story.

Comment: I struggle to think of a work of fiction (even the ones not set on Earth) that don't mention real places -- someone goes to New York or Paris, visits a famous landmark, lives in a city people have heard of. Can you be more specific about what sort of mentions you have in mind? A real business at its real location is much more specific than "Paris", for example.

Comment: @Kate I can think of a number of SF novels not set on earth and in which neither earth or any place on Earth is mentioned. Two examples: *Monument* by Lloyd Biggle and *Foreigner* by C.J. Cherryh. Some "ruritanian" works mention only places in the imagined country. This is true of some but not all of Avram Davidson's Dr Esterhazy stories, for example.

Comment: It's a good question, and I hate to discourage a new contributor, but Chenmunka is right; it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One is free to mention specific places and real people in a work of fiction if one chooses to. As long as one avoids defamation, there is no legal issue.

Whether this helps the story, by providing a sense of realism, or harms it in some way, depends on the nature of the story and the skill of the writer. But such mentions are very very common.